Why do we have Marketing Automation and Reference Data connection string on CD if xConnect Collection Service reads and writes interaction data?
In the documentation, Sitecore says the following:
The xConnect Collection service reads and writes interaction data. For example, the Content Delivery role submits web interactions to the xConnect Collection service.

In our scaled PAAS setup for Sitecore, I see connection strings for xDBMarketingAutomation and xDBReferenceData.
I am reviewing it as a part of a security exercise.
Why is it so?

They are not for writing interaction data (like somebody visiting a page). They are for connecting to different types of data and functions. You may want to check in on the docs for the different application roles: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/104/platform-administration-and-architecture/experience-platform-application-roles.html
There are also docs about the data flows that might help with your security exercise.

@JasonSt-Cyr: Can you please help me with the docs about the data flow?

In the documentation site I shared, there's another section called "Data flows and processes": https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/104/platform-administration-and-architecture/data-flows-and-processes.html

We need details of xDBMarketing Automation inside CD server, since when CD role receives a live marketing event, it sends the contact and interaction data to the MA Operations role, which processes the contact in the same way that the MA Engine does for work items.
Moreover with respect to Reference Data service, it allows trusted clients outside of XP to submit and retrieve reference data, thereby extending the xDB Reference Data database with outside concepts and data.
You can find more details on the same here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/marketing-automation.html
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/collecting-experience-data.html
Hope this helps!!!
